# No entering Credentials for an SQL Azure report

Tags: reporting, azure-sql-database, credentials

Situation:

I have set up an Windows Azure webrole in visual studio 2010 to get a SQL report from the reportserver  and everything works.

Problem:

Everytime I want to check the report and run the program I have to enter the credentials for the report, I don't know how to turn this off. Even on the server I have to enter them but I can't seem to find a way to make the report public.. 
I find the management quite confusing..

Does anybody know how to do this?
This is what it looks like when running the program

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you provided:

1. You have an ASP.NET Web Role which connects to SQL Azure Report Server
2. Whenever you launch your ASP.NET Web Role you need to enter credentials to access  the report as shown in the image
3. You are looking for a way to add username/password within the WebRole so reports can be viewed by anyone accessing the webpage.

Here is the answer:

1. In your SQL Azure Reporting via Report Viewer control based Web Role, you can add Username and Password into Global.config along with RSServer (Report Server) Name
2. This way when your ASP.NET based Report Viewer application will run, it will have required credentials already available to connect to report server.

The following link shows exact details about how you can achieve your objective:
http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/pass-summit-sql-azure-reporting_8267.html

You can get SQL Azure specific report viewer samples from the link below:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-reporting-samples.aspx

Comment: Actually, this seems to work fine, but now I have to enter the credentials for the data source.. when I fill in nothing and click 'view report' I get the error : 'One or more data sources is missing a user name'

Comment: I found the solution I just used  ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials :)

Comment: Now I made a new report, and it doesn't need datasource credentials, do you know how this is possible?

Comment: I found it :) depends on if it is a shared datasource or not :)

Comment: I just saw the comments. I would suggest you looking at "Report Server Roles" to understand how you can delegate the viewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430129.aspx